# How to Union 2 sql queries with separate Declare statements for each query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to union 2 queries with separate Declare statements but I get an error incorrect syntax

```
declare @start_date date
select @start_date = '2021-12-05'

select     
j.[dateexpensed]
from [table 1] j
left join [table 2] a
on j.jcmasterid = a.jcmasterid
where j.[dateexpensed] >= @start_date 
order by j.[dateexpensed] desc

union 

declare @glaccountingperiod int
select  @glaccountingperiod = 5073

select 
g.[date]
from [table 3] h
right join [table 4] g
on h.[id] = j.[account]
where h.[glaccountingperiod] = @glaccountingperiod
and h.[transactiontype] = 2
```

Comment: *"Any way out?"* Correct the syntax. Read the error. Look at the line it's telling you the problem is on and apply basic debugging skills. Without the code, your guess is infinitely better than ours.

Comment: Tryn declaring everything at the top (I.e. before your SELECT statement).

Comment: A `UNION` must be union 2 (or more) `SELECT` statements. You are trying to `UNION` a `SELECT` and `DECLARE`... It's `SELECT .... UNION (ALL) SELECT...;`. [UNION (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Also I find that 99% of the time people use `UNION` they really should use the much more efficient `UNION ALL` (and if the intention really is to remove duplicates, there are better ways to express that).

Comment: Considering the OP only wants 1 column here, however, this might be one of those 1%s. ;)

Comment: Given the left join (in the first SELECT query) which serves no useful purpose, that suggests to me that UNION (vs. UNION ALL) is a kludge.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do might be more apparent if we add some white space and add statement terminators (`;`), which you should be doing already:

```sql
DECLARE @start_date date;
SELECT @start_date = '2021-12-05';

SELECT j.[dateexpensed]
FROM [table 1] j
     LEFT JOIN [table 2] a ON j.jcmasterid = a.jcmasterid
WHERE j.[dateexpensed] >= @start_date
ORDER BY j.[dateexpensed] DESC
UNION
DECLARE @glaccountingperiod int;

SELECT  @glaccountingperiod = 5073;

SELECT g.[date]
FROM [table 3] h
     RIGHT JOIN [table 4] g ON h.[id] = j.[account]
WHERE h.[glaccountingperiod] = @glaccountingperiod
  AND h.[transactiontype] = 2;
```

Notice that your 3rd statement is a `UNION` of a `SELECT` and a `DECLARE`; which is why you are getting a syntax error.

Instead you need to move `DECLARE` and assigned of your variabled to  prior to the `UNION`. Also individual statements in an `UNION` statement cannot be ordered; the `ORDER BY` must go at the very end:

```sql
DECLARE @start_date date = '2021-12-05'; --You can DECLARE and assign 
DECLARE @glaccountingperiod int = 5073;  --in a single statement.

SELECT j.[dateexpensed]
FROM [table 1] j
     LEFT JOIN [table 2] a ON j.jcmasterid = a.jcmasterid
WHERE j.[dateexpensed] >= @start_date
UNION
SELECT g.[date] AS dateexpensed
FROM [table 3] h
     INNER JOIN [table 4] g ON h.[id] = j.[account]
WHERE h.[glaccountingperiod] = @glaccountingperiod
  AND h.[transactiontype] = 2
ORDER BY [dateexpensed] DESC;
```

Note I change your `RIGHT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`. This is because your `WHERE` in the query implicitly converts it to one already. If `glaccountingperiod` and `transactiontype` are both `NULL` it is impossible for them to equal `@glaccountingperiod` and `2` respectively.

Comment: works well! 1st query need to be 'order by' dateexpensed not the 2nd query. There are more columns to be added and data need to be just stacked explicitly for each query

Comment: @Sayalee as I stated *"the `ORDER BY` must go at the very end"*. You order the **entire** dataset returned. You *cannot* put an `ORDER BY` in the first `SELECT` query prior to the `UNION`. Sounds like you're adding new requirements you didn't tell us about. If so, you'll need to ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).